# How to handle focus of edittext inside viewpager2

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager2 with 5 fragments, and last fragment has Edittext
The question is, I want to requestfocus() to my edittext everytime the user choose last fragment.

What I have tried:

1. Use registerOnPageChangeCallback(), but the problem is, I can't request focus on page change cause it will cause NPE.
2. Use onresume, onattach etc, None of them called when user change between fragment
3. Setuservisisiblehint is deprecated

Any Idea for this problem will be appreciate
Thank you

EDIT:

I am sorry I forgot to mention

My Viewpager(parent) is in the last fragment of other viewpager2(child). So I have viewpager2(parent) and the last fragment contains my viewpager2(child).
When I choose the last fragment of "child" I can set focus to the edittext. But the problem is when I change the "parent" tab, and go back to last fragment that contains "child". I can't tell the "child" to focus again.

Yes Onresume, and onpause work at the "parent's" fragment, not at "child"

Thank you

Comment: I am using viewpager2 with tablayout to show two fragments where one of them has an edittext but the keyboard does not appear when I select the edittext, did your's work ?

I am referring to this issue https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/issues/107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can requestFocus , in the `onResume` method of that last fragment, with Viewpager2 any off screen fragments are capped at `onStarted` and resumed when fully on screen.

I'm not sure why you say:-

> Use onresume, onattach etc, None of them called when user change between fragment

Unless you are talking about the `Activity's` `onResume` instead here.

This behaviour is not well documented but you can see the functionality in the releasenotes
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0-alpha06

> FragmentStateAdapter: non-primary-item Fragments are capped at STARTED, and their menuVisibility is set to false.

and

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0-beta05

> Fix for ordering of Fragment pause / resume transactions when changing the page (we now always pause the old primary item before resuming the new one). (b/139489059)

You also say:-

> Setuservisisiblehint is deprecated

Which is not part of Viewpager2 but the original viewpager and the original viewpager also only resumes the current fragment.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I edit the question. I forgot to mention to you that my viewpager that we discuss first(child) is inside the last fragment of other viewpager2(parent). Please help me. And thank you before

Comment: After editing some code. The code works, thank you for mention to check the resume and pause. You save my day

Answer (score 0):

You can `requestFocus` , in the `onCreateView` method of that last fragment or `onActivityCreated` method in the activity, although I have never used that last one.

Remember that in order to `requestFocus` in the EditText you need to enable focusable in touch mode before.

You can do it through XML with:
`android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`
or with Java:
`editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);`

Comment: Thank you for answering.
But onCreateView only called when it's first created. 
If the user change the page and then go to last fragment again, none of the method get called ( oncreate, oncreatview, onattach,ondetach,onresume, onstart, onstop, ondestroy)

Comment: Well, you can use onActivityCreated or onViewStateRestored and focus the EditText